# phonegap iphone external url

Tags: iphone, ios, cordova

I'm using phonegap to create an app. I'm having a problem when I'm trying to 'include' a remote url as webpage. I have this working on Android, this was faily easy by changing the `super.loadUrl();`. After a while I found out that I could change the `startPage` (for iOS). Now I can include the remote webpage in an iOS app but phonegap doesn't seem to be loading.

No events (like the `deviceready`) will be called and I can't use the phonegap api.

Any help on this please?

Comment: I think I can help you, please tell me what do you see when trying to load the remote URL, you said "phonegap doesn't seem to be loading", what error do you see?

Comment: Hello mate, I'm not getting any errors. The page does load, content will be displayed. I have attached a devideready event to the dom but that event will be never triggered.

Comment: just for the record, I'm using the same url in an Android app and that works well

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In order for you to be able to run PhoneGap code on an external website you will need to whitelist the website. Each platform has a different way of whitelisting. For iOS you will need to add the host in PhoneGap.plist under the "ExternalHosts" key.

Comment: Yes I had to whitelist the external website before I could even load the app. But this doesn't seem to solve the problem with phonegap to run.

Comment: Just noticed you are using the same URL for both Android and iOS. Do you have some logic in your HTML to pick the proper phongeap-ver.js file? Unfortunately the .js files are platform dependent right now.

Comment: Right, didn't knew that I would need different phonegap.js files. Got it working now, thanks.

Comment: We are targeting the 1.5 release to consolidate the phonegap.js files so they are the same for all platforms.

Answer (score 0):

Where are you loading the PhoneGap.js file from? It won't fire the events if you are loading the JS file locally. The JS file will need to be loaded from the same page that you are loading remotely.

[EDIT]
Just noticed that you said you are able to browse the same URL on Android. The PhoneGap.js file is different for Android and iOS. If you are using a common file, that could be the problem.

Comment: phonegap-1.3.0.js is in the same dir as the index.php on my remote server :)