# Socket.io + PhoneGap

Tags: javascript, node.js, cordova, socket.io

When I try to use [Socket.IO](https://socket.io/) with [PhoneGap](https://phonegap.com/) I get this error:

(on iOS where socket.io should be supported)

> Origin null is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Origin.

This is because my app is served via `file://` protocol. What can I do to get around this?

Thanks!!

Answer (score 19):

You have to add the socketio host to the "ExternalHosts" key in PhoneGap.plist.

See [Faq](http://wiki.phonegap.com/w/page/41631150/PhoneGap%20for%20iOS%20FAQ):

> Q. Links to and imported files from external hosts don't load?
>
> A. The latest code has the new white-list feature. If you are referencing external hosts,
>   you will have to add the host in PhoneGap.plist under the "ExternalHosts" key. Wildcards are ok.
>   So if you are connecting to "http://phonegap.com", you have to add "phonegap.com" to the list (or use the wildcard "*.phonegap.com"
>   which will match subdomains as well). (Note: If    you open the plist
>   file in Xcode, you won't need to fiddle with the XML syntax.)

For android you have to edit cordova.xml and add access to the socketio host:

```
<access origin="HOST*"/>
```

---

index.html (with socketio example):

```
...
<script src="HOST/socket.io/socket.io.js"></script>
<script>
    var socket = io.connect('HOST');
    socket.on('news', function (data) {
        socket.emit('my other event', { my: 'data' });
    });
</script>
...
```

---

app.js (server side javascript / basic socketio example):

```
var io = require('socket.io').listen(80);

io.sockets.on('connection', function (socket) {

socket.emit('news', { hello: 'world' });
    socket.on('my other event', function (data) {
        console.log(data);
    });
});
```

---

The HOST you have to replace with hostname of your socket.io server!

Comment: Is this Android only? I'm building for iOS and dont have a cordova.xml, only a cordova.plist. Have you done this on iOS? Thanks!

Comment: Yes (cordova.xml is android only). For iOS you have to put the HOST in PhoneGap.plist (see http://stackoverflow.com/a/8972890/584545)

Comment: Adding a host to the whitelist does nothing as far as setting the orgin, which is the problem. Shazron, below (who creates PhoneGap) has the right idea, I just don't know how to do that.

Comment: For android and iOS both, I achieved it using cordova's white-list plugin. https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-whitelist

Answer (score 5):

Using PhoneGap the webpage is opened using the *file://* protocol

With *file://* protocol no origin is set to the WebSocket connection, so the browser will raise that security exception if the server doesn't set the *Access-Control-Allow-Origin* header to the response enabling [CORS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-origin_resource_sharing)

Consider using some PhoneGap plugin like the following, which uses native code to handle the connection, but enables a (hopefully standard-compatible) WebSocket API inside the webviews

Android: https://github.com/anismiles/websocket-android-phonegap

iPhone: https://github.com/remy/PhoneGap-Plugin-WebSocket

Those plugins are just the first ones I found, not sure how much they are actively developed and stable

Answer (score 2):

So if the webpage opened with the file:// url protocol in PhoneGap was to send the header "Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *"  -- theoretically it should all work with socket.io?

(it's possible to do so through NSURLProtocol, but I didn't want to go down this rabbit hole without knowing the fix)