# What is the state of websockets in PhoneGap for iOS?

Tags: javascript, ios, cordova, websocket, socket.io

What is the state of websockets in PhoneGap for iOS?

I'm trying to figure out what I need to do, if anything, to make socket.io work with my phonegap app. Thanks for any information, new to phonegap.

Comment: Have you added the URLs you wish to communicate with to Phonegap's whitelist (in the plist file?)

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you might need a plugin to do this.

This stackoverflow answer might help you:
[Socket.io + PhoneGap](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10738073/socket-io-phonegap)

Or you could jump straight to this blog entry which describes how to use the plugin:

http://remysharp.com/2010/10/04/websockets-in-phonegap-projects/

Problem appears to be that phonegap makes socket requests from file:// rather than http://

Comment: Surprisingly, the stackoverflow link you have included is again posted by @Fancy. Same User :)

Comment: LOL - so it is. I hadn't noticed that!