# Can a phonegap app using meteor be deployed to the app store?

Tags: cordova, app-store, meteor

I understand that meteor CAN be used with PhoneGap, but are there any examples out in the wild of phonegap apps using meteor that have been approved on the app store?

I have published several non-meteor apps using PhoneGap, so I understand the process. I believe the issue that Apple may have with meteor is the ability of a meteor app to live-update the code.

Comment: I'd love to know this as well

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**UPDATE**:

Meteor's client/server communication is done through the use of `WebSockets`. AFAIK, `WebSocket` is doable with PhoneGap and will not get your app rejected (iOS or Android). There may be some work involved to enable the use of `WebSockets` with PhoneGap. Here's a StackOverflow post about it:

[Socket.io + PhoneGap](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10738073/socket-io-phonegap)

As for App Store apps built with PhoneGap and Meteor, I think it's too hard to find any at this moment.

---

**ORIGINAL**:

I don't think anyone can answer this definitively. This is because Apple will rate and reject your app based on your content, performance, and presentation.

If your PhoneGap app feel like a web app or runs slow, it will get rejected.

Here's my personal experience (not with meteor in particular).

My company developed an app with PhoneGap and SenchaTouch earlier this year. It got rejected on the Apple App Store because the reviewer thought the app felt too webapp-like. Our app, with the help of SenchaTouch, looked very native. But there was a noticeable performance difference. And I think that's what ultimately caused the rejection.

In the end, we had to go native, because there was no way to achieve the same performance otherwise. I think Mark Zuckerberg also agrees.

Comment: Thanks Dave, but that's not really an answer to my question. I have published several apps to the app store using PhoneGap and they've not yet been rejected. I believe the real question is whether the ability of meteor apps to live-update the code is a stopper for Apple.

Comment: @mainsocial Personally, in the long rejection notes I've seen in the past, the reviewer never mentioned any use of underlying technology. They were mostly focused on the content and performance. But, I see your concern, so I updated the answer accordingly.