# How to do socket programming in android using phone gap

Tags: cordova, phonegap-plugins

I am working on cordova 2.7 .I need socket programming plugin for android . i found  a lot but i didn't get any thing .I am plugin for IOS bt problem in android .Is there any link where these plugins are available .I know some of the plugins are deprecated . If some one use recently in their project please share experience with us.

Thanks

Comment: Have you looked into http://socket.io/ ?  Also take a look at this post here - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10738073/socket-io-phonegap

Comment: can you please explain more in detail ? My simple part is i run my server on my local machine .I need to print that data on my device .having port 8180.How to get that data .Give some example my Ip =192.186.12.1.First i need to connect to server .Than get same data with is running in my machine