# Unable to connect to socket.io from html file served via different server or file system

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, socket.io

I'm trying to learn [node.js](/questions/tagged/node.js) and [socket.io](/questions/tagged/socket.io).

Most of the examples online, including the [official one](http://socket.io/get-started/chat/) asks to setup the following at server side:

```
var app = require('express')();
var http = require('http').Server(app);
var io = require('socket.io')(http);

app.get('/', function(req, res){
  res.sendfile('index.html');
});

io.on('connection', function(socket){
  console.log('a user connected');
});

http.listen(3000, function(){
  console.log('listening on *:3000');
});
```

and this in client side:

```
<script src="/socket.io/socket.io.js"></script>
<script>
  var socket = io();
</script>
```

So this uses the same server for serving the `index.html`as well as handling the socket connections, and it looks like [sockets.io](/questions/tagged/sockets.io) creates a `socket.io` js file under `socket.io` directory on the server. All good up to this.

---

Now, I'm working on a [cordova](/questions/tagged/cordova) application, I don't have to serve the `index` file from a server as of now since it'll be bundled with the application. I just need to connect to the socket server running in my local machine on a particular port.

Also, I don't want to use express, because I'm learning - I don't think it's required for simply setting up a socket server, I rather not use it without understanding what it does or how it makes my life easier (In other words *I rather understand a thing or two about javascript before jumping into the world of jquery...*).

So I tried the following in my server.js file:

```
var port = 80;
io = require('socket.io')(port);
console.log('socket server started @ %s !', port);
```

executing this via `node server.js` command prints `socket server started @ 80 !`

According to the [documentation](http://socket.io/docs/#sending-and-receiving-events) that should create an `http` server (*probably enhanced by socket.io with awesome stuff*) listening to port `80`.

Now if I load the `index.html` via a `node.js` server launched by the brackets IDE at `http://127.0.0.1:56958/...path/index.html` which contains the following:

```
<script src="scripts/libs/socket.io/socket.io.js"></script>
<script>
    console.log('test');
    var socket = io('http://127.0.0.1:80');
</script>
```

(Where `scripts/libs/socket.io/socket.io.js` is the standalone `sockets.io` client side library which I downloaded form their [github repo](https://github.com/socketio/socket.io-client/blob/master/socket.io.js))
Which leaves me with the following error in latest version of chrome:

```
Refused to execute inline script because it violates the following Content Security Policy directive: "default-src 'self' data: gap: https://ssl.gstatic.com 'unsafe-eval'". Either the 'unsafe-inline' keyword, a hash ('sha256-2j6JUXRmZBJXdmMDTRd3ZxygBJNrb8gSbgOi4FOjiy0='), or a nonce ('nonce-...') is required to enable inline execution. Note also that 'script-src' was not explicitly set, so 'default-src' is used as a fallback.
```

I also tried loading `index.html` file from file system using `file:///` protocol, which throws the same error.

What am I doing wrong, and how can I fix this?

---

Note: I have seen [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10738073/socket-io-phonegap) question, but I don't have a `cordova.xml` file since I'm not using cordova to build the app yet. I've tried enabling cross origin resource sharing (*using an extension from store*), but that didn't help either.

---

**Update:**

Below is the directory structure:

```
root
 |_app
 | | // lots of cordova directories and files like package.json
 | |_www
 |  |_scripts
 |  | |_libs
 |  |   |_socket.io
 |  |     |_socket.io.js
 |  |_index.html
 |_node_modules
 | |_socket.io
 |_server
   |_server.js
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The plugin **cordova-plugin-whitelist** is blocking your socket.io connection. You can look at configuration details [here](https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-whitelist). You'll want to configure it carefully, but for the purpose of testing you can allow everything:

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" content="default-src *;">
```

Comment: But that only applies when I'm using cordova to build the app, right..? I'm simply running it using [brackets](http://brackets.io/). Does the `node.js` server launched by brackets consider cordova plugins..?

Comment: This is a client-side error - not a server-side one.